# I imported an image in my project in unity and it doesn't blend with the lighting ; cause in the dark light i can still see the image pretty clear

Tags: c#, windows, image, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I imported an image instead of a 3d model for am enemy, and the game is supposed to be in dark at night but the image is not blending with the rest of the environment so can anyone plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is set to sprite it uses an unlit shader that does not respond to lighting. If you have it on a material as the albeto channel on a 3D plane, it will respond to lighting but only as a flat surface. Unless you also have a normal map for it.